# In GruntJS: naming target file with the same name as the source file

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

In GruntJS, is there any way to name a file generated by a task with the same name as the source file.

For example, if you wanted to compile all `.less` files to individual `.css` files, is there any way to do it like this:

```
files: {
    "css/<%= target-filename %>.css": ["less/*.less"]
}
```

where `<%= target-filename %>` is the value of `*` of that current `.less` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [files-array format](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files-array-format). you can specify an output extension. see this [documentation](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically)

something like this should do the trick

```
  files: [
    {
      expand: true,     // Enable dynamic expansion.
      src: ['less/*.less'], // Actual pattern(s) to match.
      dest: 'css/',   // Destination path prefix.
      ext: '.css',   // Dest filepaths will have this extension.
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer lies in the documentation for [building the files object dynamically](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically).

You need to update your code to use `expand: true` as well as using `src`, `dest` and `cwd`.

Example in the [files array format](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files-array-format) assuming the use of grunt-contrib-less plugin:

```
files: [{
  expand: true, // The magic switch for processing files 1:1
  cwd: '<%= target-less-dir %>/',
  src: ['*.less'],
  dest: '<%= target-css-dir %>'
}]
```